# Why do I get "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification" in Android Studio 3.2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have read the article  [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

But I still get the following information  after I add the code implementation `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'`, why?

**Information**

*All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 more... (Ctrl+F1)*

The information keep even if I Clean project and Rebuild Project.

**Code**

You can download the code at https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlg731ovf7h3bmi/NewMyApplication.zip?dl=0

**Image1**

[image]

**Image2**
[image]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some or one of your libraries use an old version of `customtabs` internally, that's why this warning message is showing. If you implement this with the latest version then the warning will be gone.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
```

After adding this I have also shown the same error for another older version of dependencies. After adding this also all warning is gone.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Also you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/5167909

Answer (score 0):

I think that `play-services-ads:17.0.0` include appcompat 26.1.0. Try to exclude it:

```
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I needn't add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0` when appcompat  is 26.1.0 or above?

Comment: You can use it, but it seems that `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0` uses old version of appcompat. `exclude group: "com.android.support"` need to help you

Answer (score 0):

For now, just include `noninspection` to suppresses the warning

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

Everything will work fine.